# el-date-picker sets default-value only to the year and month, and the day cannot be highlighted

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I am using el-date-picker component,my expectation is to using :default- value to set the default highlight date to a specified date instead of current local date.
but the fact is the drop-down box can locate to 2019-02 ,and the expected date is not highlighted, what is wrong here?

```
<el-date-picker
  v-model="value8"
  type="date"
  placeholder="Pick a date"
  :default-value="defaultDate">
```

```
data() {
return {
  defaultDate: new Date('2019-02-22')
}}
```

see my jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/48ehxz9n/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the styles do not have a definition for the class [`default`](https://github.com/ElementUI/theme-chalk/blob/master/src/date-picker/date-table.scss), and this is the reason to open the [`issue`](https://github.com/ElementUI/theme-chalk/issues/new). As an auxiliary solution, add a definition manually:

```
.el-date-table td.default span {
    color: #409eff;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/7cw5rz3u/ ]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the selected date to the default date if you are expecting that is to be highlighted on click of date time picker

html

```
<div id="app">
<template>
  <div class="block">
    <span class="demonstration">date</span>
    <el-date-picker
      v-model="selectedDate"
      type="date"
      placeholder="Pick a date"
      :default-value="defaultDate">
    </el-date-picker>
    {{defaultDate}} |
    {{selectedDate}}
  </div>
</template>
</div>
```

JS

```
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
    selectedDate: new Date('2019-02-22'),
    defaultDate: new Date('2019-02-22')
    }
  }
}
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```